# How to avoid multiple open in particular application in android?

Tags: android, email, launcher

I have already opened my android application. I used url scheme, so that my app can be opened from the users email. But if i try to open my application from clicking email link from the web browser, it will open that application in separate window. (Please see my attached screen short picture) .

How to avoid my application to open twice separately?[image]

```
<activity
android:name="com.mYs3.MainActivity.flash_screen"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>            
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="mYs3" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this line in your activity block in manifest

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. its working fine but if i minimize the app then its again get launching the app but i need to resume

Comment: check whether onDestroy method is invoked when you minimize your app, if so, something is causing it getting destroyed for some reason and you should investigate this. the singleTask attribute is not affecting this behaviour